# C++ vs C# - array

Tags: c#, c++

Let's have an array `a = {0,1,2,3,4}` and an `int i = 2`. Now let's do few operations in both (always starting from the point above).

```cs
a[i] = i++; // a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
a[i] = ++i, // a = {0, 1, 3, 3, 4}
```

This seems logical to me. But for C++, I get different results:

```cpp
a[i] = i++;  // a = {0, 1, 2, 2, 4}
a[i] = ++i;  // a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I don't understand the results I get in C++;

Comment: In C++, it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: You can't really compare two very different languages with very different semantics like this. At least not without understanding the semantics in both languages very well, which would mean you would not actually need to ask this question.

Comment: @rsp It is before C++17 :P

Comment: Executed right to left in cpp.

Answer (score 7):

C# evaluates from left to right, so in the first case, you get:

```
a[2] = 2; // 1)
a[2] = 3; // 2)
```

In C++, that is undefined behavior, but since C++17, an assignment operator is evaluated from right to left:

```
a[3] = 2; // 1)
a[3] = 3; // 2)
```

Different languages, different rules.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was asking for :-)